# C++ static library and constructor

Tags: c++, static-libraries

I was following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx to create a static library and use it in other projects located in the same solution. It works fine with static functions; However, when I try to create a constructor, it gives me `error LNK2019: unresolved symbol` and `error LNK1120`. Am I not allow to create a constructor in static library??

Loogger.h

```
namespace logger
{
    class Logger
    {
    public:
        Logger(int i);
        ~Logger();
    }
}
```

Logger.cpp

```
namespace logger
{  
    Logger::Logger(int i)
    {
        clog << "In the constructor" << i << endl;
    }
}
```

Main.cpp: (in a separate project)

```
int main(void)
{
    Logger log(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: do you have a reference to your lib in the main project?

Comment: yes, i think. 'coz the static functions work..

Comment: @ldov I'd suspect so (OP says `It works fine with static functions`) ...

Comment: 1) Can you post the full error message?
2) Can you post the full console output of the build?

The error is coming from the linker you are probably no linking the static lib to main..

Comment: okay, will do so right now!!

Comment: Did you declare a destructor but didn't implement it? (is this your actual code?)

Comment: You've been missing to define a destructor function for `Logger`.

Comment: Oh My GOODDD~~ Thank you guys so much!!! OAO I'm stuck on this for hours now...

Comment: Yes, I didn't define the destructor in the cpp

Comment: I stumbled upon your question while searching for answer to a similar problem I was facing. I was getting compilation error for constructor even though it was defined. The problem in my case was that constructor had TCHAR* parameter. While my static lib was using unicode, the project consuming this static lib wasn't. I had to set "Use Unicode Character Set" in project properties of both applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to define a destructor function for your `Logger` class:

```
Logger::~Logger()
{
}
```

Either omit the declaration for it (the compiler creates a default version), or do as shown above.

Comment: Won't the compiler generate a default destructor ?

Comment: @NipunTalukdar If you don't declare one it would (I mentioned that), I believe the OP wasn't showing that in his code sample honestly.

Comment: Right, I thought it was unrelated to the context. I'll edit my mistake so it can be visible.